# Erro: "update were reject because the remote work that you do not have locally"

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando armazenar um projeto para o GitHub pelo git, porém quando uso o comando:

```
git push oringin master
```

Apresenta esta mensagem:

> Updates were reject because the remote work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrates the remote changes before pushing again.

Tradução:

> Atualizações foram rejeitadas devido ao trabalho remoto que você não tem localmente. Isso geralmente é causado por um outro repositório executando push para o mesmo ref. Você pode querer primeiro integrar as alterações remotas antes de executar o comando push novamente.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Escrever "Alguem me ajuda" ou titulos pouco intuitivos é totalmente redundante, procure olhar outras perguntas e analisar como o pessoal faz, outra coisa a palavra `sub` no português não tem nada haver com `subi` ou `subir`. Entenda isto como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Tem certeza que é `oring` ? O comando correto não é `git push origin master`?

Comment: E isto esqueci de coloca origin, eu estava armazenando normal cada versao do projeto no github, porem depois que cliquei na opção readme la no github, coloquei alguns comentários, esta apresentando esse erro agora quando tenta da um push. Voce sabe como resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está dizendo que o repositório tem modificações que você não possui no seu repositório local. Então você tem deve primeiro dar um "pull" para atualizar seu código local e depois dar um push.

```
git pull origin master.
git push origin master.
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, realmente resolveu meu problema, ainda pensei em da um git pull , porem nao sabia que resolveria o problema , agradeço amigo.